# function forward-declaration inside another function

Tags: c++, c, static, forward-declaration

Code goes first:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    void bar(int);  //is this forward-decl legal?
    bar(x);
}

void bar(int x)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

In the code above, `foo` calls `bar`, usually I put the forward-decl of `bar` outside of `foo`, like this:

```
void bar(int);
void foo(int x) 
{
    bar();
}
```

First, I think it's OK to put `bar`'s forward-decl inside `foo`, right?

Second, consider this, if `bar` is a `static` function like this:

```
static void bar(int x)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Then how should I forward-declare it? I mean should the forward-decl take or omit the `static`?

Comment: If this is C++, then you should *not* have the "c" tag on your question, and *should* be using an unnamed namespace rather than the `static` keyword. If this is C, then you should *not* have the "c++" tag on your question, and *should* be marking your forward-declarations as `static`.

Comment: @ruakh: Use of `static` isn't deprecated, though some people persist in saying it is.  `static` and unnamed namespaces each have their own advantages.

Comment: @BenVoigt, advantages? Such as?

Comment: @Alcott: Not bloating the external names table, which means less work for the linker.  The big advantage of the unnamed namespace in C++03 was that it was compatible with template parameters, but in C++11 they no longer require external linkage.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for that information. (For the benefit of anyone reading this who, like me, had encountered that persistent statement, and is surprised by Ben Voigt's comment: as it turns out, some working drafts of C++11 said that `static` was deprecated "when declaring objects in a namespace scope", but that statement was later removed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes it's legal to put a forward-declaration inside another function.  Then it's only usable in that function.  And the namespace of the function you put it inside will be used, so make sure that matches.
2. The Standard says: "The linkages implied by successive declarations for a given entity shall agree."  (section 7.1.2).  So yes, the prototype must be `static` also.  However, it doesn't look like putting a prototype of a `static` linkage function inside another function is allowed at all.  "There can be no `static` function declarations within a block" (same section).

Comment: So simply put, I can't forward-declare `bar` inside `foo`, if `bar` is `static`, right?

Comment: @Alcott: According to my reading of the Standard, that's right.  I would test with Comeau try-it-out, they have near-perfect compliance to the Standard (well, C++03, and they're working on C++11).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is fine to put the forward declaration inside the function. It doesn't matter where it is as long as the compiler has seen it before you call the function. You can forward-declare functions in namespaces as well. However, prototypes are limited to the scope they are in:

```
int blah() {
    { void foo(); }

    foo(); // error: foo not declared
}
```

Secondly, you only need to put `static` on the *prototype*, else the compiler will complain about `bar` being declared `extern` (all prototypes are implicitly `extern` unless they are explicitly marked otherwise by e.g. `static`). Note that `static` function prototypes cannot appear inside a function.

Comment: By "static function prototypes cannot appear inside a function", did you mean, if `bar` is `static`, then I can't forward declare `void bar(int);` or `static void bar(int);` inside `foo`?

Comment: You can't forward declare a function in a different namespace though.

Comment: @Alcott you can't forward declare `static void bar(int);` inside `foo`.